# Ember.js computed property to return model ID array?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Updated: 11:36PST 07 Dec 2017

All I'm trying to do is create an array containing a list of current ID's in the model to use in a child component, but somehow seem to be missing something obvious. If it is relevant, I am using Ember 2.17.0 with Ember Data 2.17.0 as well.

The route returns an array of models very similar to a `findAll`, but modified to work with a REST endpoint I do not have any control over. I need an array of the id's from the model to use in a component embedded in the route. Based on feedback, I have attempted to implement this in both the route *and* the controller.

In the controller, I'm trying it this way.

```
searchIdArrayC: computed('model', () => {
  return this.get('model').map((record) => record.get('reachId'));
})
```

..and in the route I'm trying it this way.

```
searchIdArrayR: computed('model', () => {
  return this.modelFor('reaches').map((record) => record.get('reachId'));
});
```

When I look at it in the Chrome Ember Inspector, for both the route and controller it is telling me `Error while computing: searchIdArrayR` or `Error while computing: searchIdArrayC`.

Just to try and do some testing, I sent both the route and the controller to the console. With both the route and controller, the aforementioned methods are working, so I am really confused.

[image: Ember Inspector]

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you may be able to offer.

Answer (score 0):

In route file, `model` is a function, but you are treating it like `model` property which is available in the corresponding controller.

If you can move `searchIdArray` computed property to corresponding controller then that should work.

Comment: You could also keep it in the route if using [`modelFor` method of Route](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=modelFor). So it would be `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` instead of `this.get('model')`.

Comment: I've tried to implement both of these suggestions, and updated the question to reflect my attempts. Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of arrow function `() => ` you can simply use `function(){`... Refer [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/bdf60a30440a7b599d60e579e28e1d17?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Comment: Wow, @kumkanillam, do I ever feel stupid. Only about six hours of my life was wasted on that...thank you for the help, even if it was this foolish.